# Twilio on Azure Functions(2.0)

Tags: azure, twilio, azure-functions

I'm currently writing a Azure Functions code to send SMS through Twilio.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Types;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;

public static void Run(string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");

    string accountSid = "My_SID";
    string authToken = "MY_TOKEN";

    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

    var _to = new PhoneNumber("+821073884889");
    var _from = new PhoneNumber("+15672805833");

    var message = MessageResource.Create(to: _to, from: _from, body: "Hello world");
}
```

When I run this code, i got below error messages

```
2018-11-09T14:06:47  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2018-11-09T14:07:28.742 [Information] Executing 'Functions.sendSMSFunction2' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=c21afe21-8af0-4dde-a730-236377f790b9)
2018-11-09T14:07:28.772 [Error] Executed 'Functions.sendSMSFunction2' (Failed, Id=c21afe21-8af0-4dde-a730-236377f790b9)
Method not found: 'Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.MessageResource Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.MessageResource.Create(Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber, System.String, Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber, System.String, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Uri>, System.Uri, System.String, System.Nullable`1<System.Decimal>, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, System.String, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, System.String, ContentRetentionEnum, AddressRetentionEnum, System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, Twilio.Clients.ITwilioRestClient)'.
2018-11-09T14:08:47  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2018-11-09T14:09:48  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
```

I deleted SID and TOKEN right before pasting on here :)

So the problem looks like the MessageResource.Create part (as 4th line mentioned above)

When i run above code on VS2017, it sends the SMS well but on Azure Functions, got stucked :(

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "myqueue",
      "connection": "servicebus8_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS"
    }
  ]
}
```

function.proj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Twilio" Version="5.21.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out some of codes are not working on the Azure Function v2.

I changed version to 1 then, it worked :)

If someone like me who just copy and paste lines of code from Visual Studio, then remember 'Method not found' means downgrade the version.

I wish this one prevents other people to waste their precious time!!